# Passing a String from PHP to a JavaScript function

Tags: php, javascript, string

I am trying to write a code to pass a PHP string when clicked on the table:

```
<?php
    echo("<td onclick = 'print_("$file[$i]->Name");' >". $files[$i]->Name."</td>");  
?>
```

Where `files[]` is an array, and each element is a class with Name as a string, and it is put in a `for` loop.
I am trying to pass it to a JavaScript function where I need the name there, and it's not working. I tried passing the `i` variable and it was passed correctly so I thought there should be a special syntax for dealing with strings.

```
function print_(var x)  {
    alert(x);
}
```

Comment: How familiar are you with JavaScript and its libraries? You could use jQuery (a JavaScript library) to expedite your process...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put quotes around the string. try this:

```
echo("<td onclick = 'print_(\'".$file[$i]->Name."\');' >". $files[$i]->Name."</td>");
```

also make sure your $file[$i]->Name doesn't contain quotes

Comment: This is correct.  If you view the question's output in the browser, you're seeing something like "print_(John Doe);" which is not valid.

Comment: could be a problem there. can you post the print_ function ?

Comment: well no i wrote it when i was writing the question its working just fine on the code, coz as i said when passing an integer it shows is using the alert function but when i try passing a string it doesnt work!

Answer (score 0):

You could write the value and not display it. Then display it when clicked:

```
echo("<td id='" . $i . "' onclick='javascript:show(" . $i . ")'><p>" . $files[$i]->Name . "</p></td>");
```

then set the p-tag's visibility to hidden, and show it using the show() function. if this doesn't do it for you i suggest you do it with an ajax call :)

Comment: this is an assignment for school,the first part should be done using javascript and PHP and Ajax will be used in the next question

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<?php
...
$scriptCode="";
...(looping) 

echo("<td id='print_td$i' >". $files[$i]->Name."</td>");
$scriptCode .= '$("#print_td'.$i.'").click(function(){
  var id = '.$i.';
  //Do whatever JS you need to here, possibly: print_(id);
});';

... (end loop)

?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  <?php echo $scriptCode; ?>
});
</script>
```

This is a little more extensive, but it will get you more flexibility in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to quoting and concatenating as matei suggested, your function is failing because `function print_(var x)` is not valid JavaScript.  You don't need the var in the function declaration.  Just declare it like this: `function print_(x)`

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the answer (even though it did not make sense)

You would expect this to work...

```
echo '<td onclick="showPicture("' . $pic . '")><img src="' . $row['imgRef'] . '" height="60"; /></td>';
```

but in actual fact, this works...

```
echo '<td onclick=showPicture(' . $pic . ')><img src=' . $row['imgRef'] . ' height="60"; /></td>';
```

You will see that you actually have to omit the quotes where you would normally expect to see them.